# Getting implicit property names on a db.Model in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I get access to the implicit property names of a db.Model in Google App Engine? In particular, assume I have the following:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
  specific = db.IntegerProperty()


class Bar(db.Model):
 foo = db.ReferenceProperty(Foo, collection_name = "bars")
```

if I attempt to get the property names on Foo, like so:

```
my_foo = Foo(specific = 42)
for key, prop in my_foo.properties().iteritems()
    print "HERE bars won't show up"
```

then the my_foo.bars property doesn't show up. Or am I totally mistaken?

Any help greatly appreciated

*edited model to be Python, not ruby*

Answer (score 2):

(That model definition looks like a strange hybrid of Python and Ruby.)

I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve here, but you can get a list of model property members using introspection:

```
[x for x in dir(Foo) if isinstance(getattr(Foo,x), db.Property)]
```

If you're just trying to add instances of Bar to Foo, you should create new Bar instances with their foo fields pointing at the Foo instance:

```
foo = Foo(specific=42)
foo.put()
Bar(foo=foo).put()
Bar(foo=foo).put()
logging.info("Foo bars: %r" % list(foo.bars))
```

Comment: ReferenceProperties do not permanently store a back-references on the class.  So an attribute with the name specified in collection_name is not created unit `Bar` has been defined.

Comment: Your suggestion on getting the properties doesn't seem to work (though that is what I'm trying to do). Guess I'll just use ListProperties of keys..